# Stop javascript execution if same record passed in add to list form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in my small project, here i have a form like this
[this is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI00p.jpg)

My javascript written like this

```
$("button#add2List").click(function() {
  var product= $("#slcProduct").val();
  // here i want if any of the input in the list has same product value, display error

  // else insert this product to the list
  $("div#theList").append('<div class="cave"><input type="text" name="product[]" value="'+product+'" /></div>\
  <a onclick="removePrdct(rec)">remove</a>');
});
```

i think foreach works, but it won't stop the function. how to solve this please

Comment: What is "the list"?

Comment: Keep an array of values and check in that array first

Comment: @charlietfl how to do that, in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to check `.textContent` of `"div#theList .cave"` elements to determine if current `product` is already set as `.textContent` of a `"div#theList .cave"` element

```js
$(function() {
  var list = $("div#theList"),
    productValue = $("#slcProduct");
  $("button#add2List").click(function() {
    var product = productValue.val().trim();
    var currentList = $("input", list);
    // here i want if any of the list has same product name, display error
    if (product !== "" && (!currentList.is("*") || !currentList.filter(function(i, el) {
        return el.value.indexOf(product) > -1
      }).is("*"))) {
      // else insert this product to the list
      list.append('<div class="cave"><input type="text" name="product[]" value="' + product + '" /></div>\
  <a>remove</a>');
    } else {
        if (!product) alert("no product select")
        else alert(product + " has already been added to list")
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="add2List">add to list</button>
<select id="slcProduct">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<div id="theList"></div>
```

Comment: thanks the list i want add 
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="'+product+'" />

Comment: @MohamudNeeri Where do you append `<input type="text" name="product[]" value="'+product+'" />` to `div#theList` at `javascript` at Question? You should be able to substitute `<input type="text" name="product[]" value="'+product+'" />` for `'<div class="cave">'+product+'</div>\
    <a onclick="removePrdct(rec)">remove</a>'` if expected result is `<input>` element being appended and not current html string at Question.

Comment: to post this form to PHP function to save all passed products to db table, using `foreach` keyword, that's why i give name=product[]' to this textfield

Comment: @MohamudNeeri Ok. Append the `<input>` element instead of `<div>` and `<a>` elements; or with `<div>` and `<a>` elements. The original Question concerns checking if the text of an element is not duplicated within a parent element. Not sure how `foreach` or `<input type="text">` element is related to original Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `list.append('<div class="cave"><input type="text" name="product[]" value='+product+' /></div>\
    <a onclick="removePrdct(rec)">remove</a>');`

Comment: append the list, one `div.cave` having input `type='text'` plus `a link`, each time i click the button, it appends new `textfield` and `a link` to the list; and verification catches if same product name already added to any textfield in the div#list

Comment: @MohamudNeeri Yes, that is what `javascript` at Answer should achieve.

Comment: Thank you, but pls check my question again, i did some changes, sorry for altering, but that's what i want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array called `products` and every time button is clicked check if the selected option value is there in the array. If not append the div and add the product to the `products` array.

To exit early you can just `return`.

See sample code below:

```js
var products = [];
$("button#add2List").click(function() {
  var product = $("#slcProduct").val();
  // here i want if any of the list has same product name, display error
  if (products.indexOf(product) > -1) {
    alert('The product is already there');
    return;
  } else {
    $("div#theList").append('<div class="cave">' + product + '</div><a onclick="removePrdct(rec)">remove</a>');

    products.push(product);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add2List">Add</button>
<select id="slcProduct">
        <option value="value1">text1</option>
        <option value="value2">text2</option>
</select>
<div id="theList"></div>
```